# result of getServletName() is jsp always despite the actual name given by me

Tags: jsp

My output is not coming right though this is a simple code.
getServletName() always prints out "jsp"

and initparameter values print out "mull" always. Why is it????pls help.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"       xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

<servlet>  
<servlet-name>FirstJSP</servlet-name>  
<jsp-file>/index.jsp</jsp-file>  

<init-param>  
<param-name>dname</param-name>  
<param-value>sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver</param-value>  
</init-param>  

<init-param>
<param-name>defaultuser</param-name>
<param-value>Default User Name</param-value>
</init-param>
</servlet>  

<servlet-mapping>  
<servlet-name>FirstJSP</servlet-name>  
<url-pattern>/index</url-pattern>  
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

index.jsp

```
<%String name=request.getParameter("username");
out.println("Welcome "+name+"!!");%>
<% String driver=getServletConfig().getInitParameter("dname");  
out.print("driver name is="+driver);   %>
 <br> Servlet name is: <%= getServletConfig().getServletName() %>
<br>
Default user is: <%= getServletConfig().getInitParameter("defaultuser") %>
<br>
Parameter is: <%= getServletConfig().getInitParameter("defaultuser") %>
<br>
<%=getServletContext().getAttribute("servlet") %>
```

form.html

```
<form action="index.jsp">
<table>
    <tr><td>username: <input type="text" name="username"></td></tr><tr></tr>
    <tr><td>password: <input type="password" name="password"></td></tr>
    <tr><td align="right"><input type="submit" value="login"></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: someone help pleasee....................

Answer (score 0):

The `<url-pattern>` in the last line of your `web.xml` should be `/index.jsp`
i.e.
`<url-pattern>/index.jsp</url-pattern>`  instead of `<url-pattern>/index</url-pattern>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to access your jsp via correct servlet mapping to get its correct servlet name and init parameters. Change your form to `/index` as below (this is correct mapping of that jsp as servlet).

```
<form action="/index">
```

If you provide `index.jsp` URI it is not using configuration provided in web.xml, but just accessing staight jsp, that's why you have different name and null for init parameters.